# How get all results for translated word using google translate api

Tags: java, android, google-translate, translate

When We translate from one language to another language we will have to many results

For example when we translate "book" from English to Spanish

https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#auto/es/book

there is many results

Is there a way to get all these results using google translate api on jave and android ؟

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the google  transalte api for this purpose. It'll translate the given input to desire output results in JSON so you have to parse it.